# Where is the function graphplot defined in julia?

Tags: julia-plots

I cannot find anywhere in either of the packages

```
GraphRecipes  or  Plots
```

any line of code that defines the graphplot function.
I have used grep to search in a downloaded version of those packages.
There are a lot of usage references, but I don't see the definition.

see https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/GraphRecipes/examples/
for the first example that has lowercase   graphplot

```
using GraphRecipes
using Plots

const n = 15
const A = Float64[ rand() < 0.5 ? 0 : rand() for i=1:n, j=1:n]
for i=1:n
    A[i, 1:i-1] = A[1:i-1, i]
    A[i, i] = 0
end

graphplot(A,
          markersize = 0.2,
          node_weights = 1:n,
          markercolor = range(colorant"yellow", stop=colorant"red", length=n),
          names = 1:n,
          fontsize = 10,
          linecolor = :darkgrey
          )
```